# Extend send method of Object class

Tags: ruby

I want to change the send method in Ruby. My code is as follow

```
class A
  def send(symbol, *args)
     #customize code here
     #finally call the orinial __send__ function
     __send__(symbol, args)
  end
end
```

However, when I call the send function such as obj.send('a_var=', 10), I got this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

The error is at the line call __ send__ function.
So how can I fix this error.

Comment: Show us the body of the function `a_var=` and the **full error stack**. What class's object is `ob`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the `*args` through to the `__send__` call as individual arguments instead of an array, you need to deconstruct it there as well:

```
__send__(symbol, *args)
```

Comment: Thank you, I've changed as your suggest and finally it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me your code is ok:

```
class A
  def send(symbol, *args)
     #customize code here
     #finally call the orinial __send__ function
     p 'this method has been called'
     __send__(symbol, args)
  end
  def show=(m)
   p m
  end

end

A.new.send('show=',1,3,4)
A.new.send('show=',1)
A.new.send(:show=,1)
```

*Output:*

```
"this method has been called"
[1, 3, 4]
"this method has been called"
[1]
"this method has been called"
[1]
```